# wxc-0.91.0.0 failed to install

Tags: haskell, wxwidgets, cabal, reactive-banana

I'm trying to install reactive-banana, wx, wxcore in cabal sandbox. When `cabal install --only-dependencies` is run following error message is given:

```
src\cpp\eljlistctrl.cpp: In function 'int ListCmp(long int, long int, long int)':
src\cpp\eljlistctrl.cpp:16:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
src\cpp\eljlistctrl.cpp:16:53: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
src\cpp\eljlistctrl.cpp: In function 'bool wxListCtrl_SortItems(wxListCtrl*, void*, void*)':
src\cpp\eljlistctrl.cpp:478:41: error: cast from 'EiffelSort* {aka _EiffelSort*}' to 'long int' loses precision [-fpermissive]
src\cpp\eljlistctrl.cpp:478:44: error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)(long int, long int, long int)' to 'wxListCtrlCompare {aka int (*)(long long int, long long int, long long int)}' [-fpermissive]
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/msw/listctrl.h:342:10: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'bool wxListCtrl::SortItems(wxListCtrlCompare, wxIntPtr)' [-fpermissive]
```

What is wrong and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in this file just seems to be wrong and uses 32 bit types even in what looks like 64 bit build. Unless it was fixed in later versions, the only solution would be to build it in 32 bits, i.e. use a 32 bit Haskell installation.